# setInterval Function does not execute

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a game using HTML and Javascript. And I need a function to be called every 2 seconds. I tried using setInterval but the function is not being called. And the browser console does not show any errors.

```js
function Apples() {
  this.Apples = [];
  this.indexCount = 0;
  this.CurrentTime;

  this.createApples = function() {
    this.Apples[this.indexCount] = new Apple();
    this.indexCount++;
  }

  this.updateApples = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.indexCount; i++) {
      this.Apples[i].positionY += 1;
      this.Apples[i].drawApple();
    }
  }
}

var apples = new Apples;
setInterval(apples.createApples, 200);
```

Comment: The interval is firing as expected. What gives you the impression that it isn't being called? (Side note: Your question says "every 2 seconds", but your code is using 200 milliseconds instead of 2000.)

Comment: Voting to close as non-reproducible.

Comment: I feel, context `this` is the problem. just use the arrow function on your methods, which set the context this . or use var that = thism or bind the context

Comment: 200 !== 2 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because of the context of this and your code is 200 milliseconds, not 2 seconds.

```js
function Apple () {
  return {
    positionY: 0,
    drawApple: function () {}
  }
}

function Apples() {
  this.Apples = [];
  this.indexCount = 0;
  this.CurrentTime;

  this.createApples = function() {
    this.Apples[this.indexCount] = new Apple();
    this.indexCount++;
    console.log("new index", this.indexCount);
  }

  this.updateApples = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.indexCount; i++) {
      this.Apples[i].positionY += 1;
      this.Apples[i].drawApple();
    }
  }
}

var apples = new Apples;
// use bind
// setInterval(apples.createApples.bind(apples), 2000);
// or use function
setInterval(() => apples.createApples(), 2000);
//setInterval(function () { apples.createApples(); }, 2000);
```